# Lipschitz continuity on functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $(V,||\cdot||)$ a normed space. Which of the following functions are Lipchitz continous?
$$V \times V \rightarrow V, (v,w) \rightarrow v + w, $$ $$\mathbb{R} \times V \rightarrow V, (\lambda,v)\rightarrow \lambda v, $$ $$V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, v \rightarrow ||v||.$$ And why?

This is what I've tried to see if the first one is Lipschitz continous but I don't know what else to do:
$d_{v}(+(v, w),+(x, y))=d v(v+w, x+y)=\|v+w-(x+y) \| = \|v+w+(-x-y)\| \leqslant\|v+w\|+\|-x-y\|=\|v+w\|+\|(-1) x+y\|=\|v+w\|+\|x+y\| \cdot 1$

Comment: You have to specify a norm on the two product spaces for this question to make sense.